# Как мне можно совместить в одном приложении ASP.NET CORE и питоновский скрипт на tensorflow.keras?

Tags: python, asp.net-core, tensorflow

В общем мне нужно обученную сетку, сохранённую в .h5 просто запустить на сервере ASP.NET CORE.
Пробовал Ironpython, но он не дружит с tensorflow. Пробовал компилировать скрипт в exe с помощью pyinstaller, но он тоже не дружит с tensorflow. Есть библиотека NuGet Keras, но она требует установленного python на сервере. Есть ещё идеи?
Или может знаете бесплатный/дешёвый сервер с поддержкой ASP.NET Core + python ?

Comment: А зачем именно на сервере с asp.net core, почему не просто python?

Comment: @CrazyElf  По двум причинам, во первых приложение уже есть, и оно на ASP.NET Core. Ну и во вторых, я не думаю что я прям так с ходу разберусь с созданием серверного приложения на плохо знакомом языке

Comment: Мне кажется, тут проще всего сделать питоновский веб-сервис на Flask, который будет получать и отдавать нужные данные вашему приложению на чём хотите. Flask он довольно простой, там в несколько строчек сервис запускается. Но конечно если хотите промышленное приложение сделать, то будет уже не так просто.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, спасибо, так и сделал, через ngrok запустил на своём ПК. Надо это всё для дипломной пока-что, так что сойдёт. Теперь осталось разобраться как файлы принимать на Flask, дело техники